# How to save IP camera snapshot in Content folder using EmguCV c#

Tags: camera, ip, emgucv, snapshot

I'm using EmguCV 3.4. I need to store snapshots from IP camera periodically(5 mins). I try to stored snapshots in the **Content folder** (ASP.NET MVC). I got access violation exception. Help me.
My Code,

```
private VideoCapture _capture = null;
private Mat _frame;

public void GetSnapshot(CameraDTO cameraDTO)
{
    CvInvoke.UseOpenCL = false;
    try
    {
        _capture = new VideoCapture(cameraDTO.CameraAccessURL);
        _capture.ImageGrabbed += ProcessFrame;

        if (StartCapture())
        {
            while (_frame == null)
            {
                //wait untill camera ready
            }

            if (_frame != null && _capture != null)
            {
                Image<Bgr, Byte> imgeOrigenal = _frame.ToImage<Bgr, Byte>();
                imgeOrigenal.Save(@ImageSavepath + @"\ImageFromCamera" + cameraDTO.camID + ".jpg");
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception excpt)
    {
    Console.WriteLine(excpt.Message);
    }
}

private bool StartCapture()
{
    if (_capture != null)
    {
        _capture.Start();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

private void ProcessFrame(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (_capture != null && _capture.IsOpened && _capture.Ptr != IntPtr.Zero && _frame != null)
        {
            _frame = new Mat();
            _capture.Retrieve(_frame, 0);
        }
    }
    catch (AccessViolationException exv)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ERROR: {0}", exv.Message);
        return;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ERROR: {0}", ex.Message);
        return;
    }
}
```

@ImageSavepath = Content folder, randomly generate the issue

Comment: Could you show some related code

Comment: Ha Bom, Could you please check the edited content?

Comment: What's inside the `RetrieveMatFrame()` function? And why you don't do anything with the mat you got from  `_capture.Retrieve(_frame, 0);` in the `ProcessFrame`?

Comment: I'm using Mat frame to save the snapshot

Comment: Image<Bgr, Byte> imgeOrigenal = _frame.ToImage<Bgr, Byte>();
                imgeOrigenal.Save(@ImageSavepath + @"\ImageFromCamera" + cameraDTO.camID + ".jpg");

Comment: sorry, RetrieveMatFrame() is not in the content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you use `_frame` in another thread (cross-thread manipulating). You should save the image inside `FrameProcess()`.

```
private void FrameProcess(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (_capture != null && _capture.IsOpened && _capture.Ptr != IntPtr.Zero && _frame != null)
            {
                _frame = new Mat();
                _capture.Retrieve(_frame, 0);
                Image<Bgr, Byte> imgeOrigenal = _frame.ToImage<Bgr, Byte>();
                imgeOrigenal.Save(@ImageSavepath + @"\ImageFromCamera" + cameraDTO.camID + ".jpg");
            }
        }
        catch (AccessViolationException exv)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ERROR: {0}", exv.Message);
            return;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ERROR: {0}", ex.Message);
            return;
        }
    }
```